# Datetime conversion issue with SQL server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, powerdesigner

I've generated some fake data for a database i've created using PowerAMC. This database as some filed with timedate format. But when i'm running the file in SQL server (Express edition), i've the following :

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

The line concerned :

```
insert into INVENTORY (INVENTORY_ID, STATUS, START_DATE, COMPLETION_DATE) values (7, 'MAHSTDIV9', '1005-5-19 9:48:44', '1235-2-16 9:42:10')
```

So I think that the date format is not the expected one (maybe **dd-mm-yyyy** instead of what I have) but I dind't find out what I could do to prevent that.

What I've done so far:
Try to convert the date

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME,'345-12-9 3:23:52',120) 
    -> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
select CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),'345-12-9 3:23:52',120) AS datetime) 
    -> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Do you have any idea about how to fix it ?

Comment: What date does `345-12-9` represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datetime only goes back to 1753. Use datetime2 instead, datetime2 was introduced in sql server 2008

example

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME2,'0345-12-9 3:23:52')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i've now the following : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. What I've done : change data type into datetime2 and change the insert to CONVERT(DATETIME2, '1005-5-19 9:48:44', 120) (I've the same when I remove the "120" format). Do you know why ?

Comment: works for me, try adding 0 to the month  `select CONVERT(DATETIME2, '1005-05-19 9:48:44') `

Comment: For those who have the same issue : take care of the format of date and time : 09:49:44 (I added it too and it's now working). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In transact SQL `datetime`'s range starts from 1753 jan. 1.

You should Use `datetime2`

Answer (score 1):

`Datetime` dataype can hold dates in the range 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31. To accomodate values before year 1753 use `date` or `datetime2` datatypes.